# Unable to delete product entry in catalog flat tables on deleting product from admin in Magento2

Tags: product, magento-2.2.5, reindex, delete, flat-catalog

I have enable catalog flat tables configuration.
I try to delete product from admin but still it is displaying in frontend with message "Out of stock".
Also i checked database entry for table catalog_product_flat_1 it still showing in it.

It get remove from table as well as frontend only after reindex.
Is there any other solution to delete product from catalog flat tables without reindex ?

Comment: Setup cron. It will take care of the reindexing process automatically.

Comment: Is there any other way to add reindex along with delete functionality ?

Comment: You can trigger the indexing process after Delete event with an observer.